# Highlight table row with duplicate table cell and add border to only the first top and last bottom duplicate

Tags: jquery

In my fiddle example below you will see a few highlighted sections of table rows. The first section displays correctly but the second section with three highlighted rows does not. The issue is that I am placing a border on the top of the original duplicate and on the bottom of the next duplicate. I am looking for a way to target the last next duplicate.

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/eacqgwc8/12/

**jQuery:**

```
$('tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function () {
    var cellIndex = $(this).index();
    var next = $(this).parent().next().children().eq(cellIndex)
    if ($(this).text() === $(next).text()) {
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#E6F2D3');
        $(next).parent().css('background-color', '#E6F2D3');
        $(this).parent().children().css('border-top', '1px solid #333');
        $(next).parent().children().css('border-bottom', '1px solid #333');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is?  My understanding is that you want to highlight duplicate rows and add a top and bottom border surrounding the rows, correct?  If you look at your variable output, right now you're only comparing the second (index = 1) td element of each row, is this what you intended?

Comment: Yes. Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final solution...

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/27pks5a3/1/

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
table td {
    padding: 2px;
}
.top-border {
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
}
.bottom-border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
.background {
    background-color: #E6F2D3;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var duplicate = false;
    $("table tr").each(function() {
        var $current = $(this).children(":nth-child(2)");
        var $next = $(this).next().children(":nth-child(2)");
        if($current.text() === $next.text() && !duplicate) {
            duplicate = true;
            $current.parent().children().addClass("top-border").addClass("background");
        } else if($current.text() === $next.text() && duplicate) { 
            $current.parent().children().addClass("background");
        } else if($current.text() !== $next.text() && duplicate) {
            $current.parent().children().addClass("bottom-border").addClass("background");
            duplicate = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/27pks5a3/.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
         <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table td {
    padding: 2px;
}

.top-border {
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
}

.bottom-border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.background {
    background-color: #E6F2D3;
}
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var duplicate = false;
    $("table tr").each(function() {
        var $current = $(this).children();
        var $next = $(this).next().children();
        if($current.text() === $next.text() && !duplicate) {
            duplicate = true;
            $current.addClass("top-border").addClass("background");
        } else if($current.text() === $next.text() && duplicate) { 
            $current.addClass("background");
        } else if($current.text() !== $next.text() && duplicate) {
            $current.addClass("bottom-border").addClass("background");
            duplicate = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No sorry this needs to work if there are more than just 2 duplicates in a row. jsfiddle.net/9gq624fa/2

Comment: You can finish the rest on your own.  My example gives you all the fundamental pieces.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {

            var values = [];
            var col = $("#scrollableTable tbody tr td:first-child").length;

            for (var i = 0; i < col; i++) {
                values[i] = [];
            }
            $('tr').each(function () {
                $(this).find('td').each(function (i) {
                    if (values[i].indexOf($(this).text()) > -1) {
                        $(this).addClass('duplicate');
                    }
                    values[i].push($(this).text());
                });
            });
            console.log(values);
        });

//if you want to add the the css to first colum only then

$(function () {

            var values = [];
            var col = $("#scrollableTable tbody tr td:first-child").length;

            for (var i = 0; i < col; i++) {
                values[i] = [];
            }
            $('tr').each(function () {
                $(this).find('td:first-child').each(function (i) {
                    if (values[i].indexOf($(this).text()) > -1) {
                        $(this).addClass('duplicate');
                    }
                    values[i].push($(this).text());
                });
            });
            console.log(values);
        });
```

Comment: .duplicate {
            color: red;
        }