# Highlight Duplicate rows of particular columns of html table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatable

I am using DataTable on my table and I want to highlight duplicate rows in two to three columns.
The most relevant to what I want to do was this answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831225/how-to-display-duplicate-rows-in-same-color-using-datatable)

This is what I have tried from one of the answers. But In this solution as dataTable applies pagination on table so it's considering only data on first page. If anyone have more convenient solution please do answer.

```js
    $(function() {
        var duplicate = false;
        $("table tr").each(function() {
            var $current = $(this).children();
            var $next = $(this).next().children();
            if($current.text() === $next.text() && !duplicate) {
                duplicate = true;
                $current.addClass("top-border").addClass("background");
            } else if($current.text() === $next.text() && duplicate) { 
                $current.addClass("background");
            } else if($current.text() !== $next.text() && duplicate) {
                $current.addClass("bottom-border").addClass("background");
                duplicate = false;
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.top-border {
        border-top: 1px solid #333;
    }

    .bottom-border {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    }

    .background {
        background-color: #E6F2D3;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="table1" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr No.</th>  
      <th>Timestamp</th>
      <th>Email Id</th>
      <th>Whatsapp No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td class="sorting_1">1</td>
  <td>2020-10-29 20:53:23</td>
  <td>laaa@gmail.com</td>
  <td>+916302930342</td>
  <td>Lunavath Kapil</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="sorting_1">2</td>
  <td>2020-10-29 11:49:02</td>
  <td>laaa@gmail.com</td>
  <td>+916302930342</td>
  <td>Lunavath Kapil</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="sorting_1">3</td>
  <td>2020-10-27 00:47:35</td>
  <td>hema@gmail.com</td>
  <td>+917227860350</td>
  <td>Hemali Bhadeshiya</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="sorting_1">10</td>
  <td>2020-10-26 13:52:39</td>
  <td>Ka@gmail.com</td>
  <td>+919780818089</td>
  <td>Veerpal kaur</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does it matter how the data is being loaded?  Please update your question and give us the relevant code segment that demonstrates your attempt to resolve this issue, and explain how it's not working.

Comment: @devlincarnate In the answer the table data is in array format but in my case it's already loaded so I have to work on those values.

Answer (score 3):

First, your problem has nothing to do with DataTables or how data gets loaded.
You're comparing complete rows, and the example data you gave has no duplicate rows.

If you want to inspect the values in a column against another column, you need to iterate over the `td` elements for your comparison.

The marked answer in [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145301/highlight-table-row-with-duplicate-table-cell-and-add-border-to-only-the-first-t) is a solution that works, if you adjust the code to fit your data.  So, for example, you have a duplicate value in the Email Id column, so...change the comparison to that column:

```
$(function() {
    var duplicate = false;
    $("table tr").each(function() {
        var $current = $(this).children(":nth-child(3)");
        var $next = $(this).next().children(":nth-child(3)");
        console.log($current.text());
        console.log($next.text());
        if($current.text() === $next.text() && !duplicate) {
            duplicate = true;
            $current.parent().children().addClass("top-border").addClass("background");
        } else if($current.text() === $next.text() && duplicate) { 
            $current.parent().children().addClass("background");
        } else if($current.text() !== $next.text() && duplicate) {
            $current.parent().children().addClass("bottom-border").addClass("background");
            duplicate = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wde2yo34/)

Comment: Thanks @delvin for solution. But It's not considering all data of table only first 10 of pagination. I found solution specifically for DataTable [Here](http://live.datatables.net/wisejipa/1/edit)